# Correlation Coefficient without individual data

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics

Is there a formula to calculate the correlation coefficient ($r$) when we are only given the Summary Stats and NOT the individual data?

These Summary Stats include:  $n$, Mean of the $y$'s, Std. Dev. of the $y$'s, Mean of the $x$'s, Std. Dev of the $x$'s, and the Std. Error of the $x$'s.

Comment: No covariance or the term $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i$ though, right?

Comment: @JohnK: Not really. I know of the formula $\frac{\Sigma  \left(x_i y_i\right)-n \bar{x} \bar{y}}{(n-1) s_x s_y}$ and I was actually  trying to find a link between the term you mentioned and any of the given stats.

Comment: No.  Consider shuffling whatever data generated those summary statistics so the $x$'s and $y$'s pair up differently.  The univariate statistics would be the same but you'd have all kinds of different correlations (in extreme cases you could go from a correlation of 1 to a correlation of -1).

Comment: @dsaxton: I don't know the data that generated the summary stats. All I have as a given are the summary stats I mentioned which I am trying to figure whether they can be used to calculate (r) the correlation coefficient.

Comment: My point is that you can very easily construct two situations where you have the same means and standard deviations but different correlation coefficients depending on how the $x$'s and $y$'s are *jointly* observed, so it's not possible except in trivial cases.

Comment: @dsaxton: I'm sorry I didn't get your point the first time. So basically, this can't be calculated with the given numbers since we can look into several data sets that generate the given summary stats but which correlate very differently from one set to another. I guess I need to look into some examples to convince myself of this!

Comment: Yes, this is about what we'd expect because correlation is a *bivariate* measure, so something would be wrong if we could calculate it from univariate distributions alone.

Comment: @dsaxton: Thank you very much for steering me in the right direction. I can channel my efforts now into working on negating the possibility of getting an answer rather than trying to find an actual coefficient. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in comments, summarized here below:

The answer is NO. Among the summary statistics that you listed one important one is missing, namely, the sum of products $\sum_i x_i y_i$ (or some variant of that, like $\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$.

Without that information the correlation cannot be computed. The reason is that the marginal summary stats that you have do not say anything about the pairing of the values, as an example, say you have the data $x=(1,2,3), y=(3,2,1)$ the the correlation coefficient will be -1, but if you reverse the order of the values in the $y$ vector, the correlation becomes 1. But in both cases the marginal summaries are the same, they do not depend on the pairing of the values.